# Excel formulas are not updating with data from an external file unless the external file is open

Tags: excel, file, external

I have created an excel sheet which references an external excel file/sheet. A problem I am having is that many formulas I have in my sheet do not update with information unless I open the external file at the same time. I'm sure there will be a setting somewhere to fix this but I would like this sheet to update without having to open the other excel file?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-87861952-ca9d-4d2a-a986-4d672c908d0d

The workbook that contains the links is called the destination workbook, and the workbook that is linked to it is called the source workbook. If the workbook that you have opened (called a destination file) contains links to other workbooks or files (called source files), and the source files have changed, then the links in workbook that you are opening may display information that is out of date.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Thanks for your reply, I actually have been an idiot and put below what I have done as an answer

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the reason this has not worked for me is because I have used INDIRECT in my formula and inside of the indirect function is the link to the other workbook...this is why the links were not updating on their own so just for future reference, I had this in my formula:

```
INDIRECT("'[Filename.xlsm]Employees In-System'!$g$2:$g$10004")
```

Which will not update on its own without the external excel file being open